# jQuery simple survey infrastructure

Tags: jquery, survey

I am currently constructing an online survey which consist of 10-11 questions. I am looking for a simple jQuery structure which I can slideUp() and slideDown each question .. my survey has the basic structure below

```
<div class="question">
  Question 1 ....
</div>

<div class="question noshow">
  Question 2 goes here .... 
</div>
```

I am thinkin about using jQuery command like the following:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.nextbutton').click(function() {
     $('.question').slideUp()
     $('.question').next().slideDown() 
  });

  $('.prevbutton').click(function() {
     $('.question').slideUp()
     $('.question').prev().slideDown()
  });
});
```

I am quite new to jQuery and I think i'm stuck at the logic. Please help me through the logic on how to construct a simple infrastructure for the survey.

Thank you!

Comment: are you trying to do an accordion?

Comment: Look at my edit now, I added a custom code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of these guide to create an accordion:

[**http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/exactly-how-to-create-a-custom-jquery-accordion/**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/exactly-how-to-create-a-custom-jquery-accordion/)

if you want something hand coded in 2 min I can create a Fiddle for you.

---

Edit:

Here a custom Accordion: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/AHBB3/)**

---

The code:

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="question">
        <a href="">Click here</a>
        <p>Question here?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
        <a href="">Click here</a>
        <p>Question here?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
        <a href="">Click here</a>
        <p>Question here?</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

jQuery

```
$('.question a').click(function(e) {
   $('.question').find('.open').slideUp().removeClass('open');
   $(this).siblings('p').slideDown().addClass('open');
    e.preventDefault();        
});​
```

a bit of CSS:

```
.question {border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding:10px;}
.question p {display: none;}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="questions">
<div class='question'>Qqqqqqq1</div>
<div class='question'>Qqqqqqq2</div>
<div class='question'>Qqqqqqq3</div>
<div class='question'>Qqqqqqq4</div>
</div>
<button class='prevbutton' />
<button class='nextbutton' />
```

The JS part:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $(".question").not(".question:first").hide();

  $('.nextbutton').click(function() {
      $('.question:visible').slideUp().next().slideDown() 
  });

  $('.prevbutton').click(function() {
      $('.question:visible').slideUp().prev().slideDown()
  });
});​
```

See also: http://jsfiddle.net/93S8B/